# -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, json, unrecognized-selector

Here is my code:

```
NSString *url = @"https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=API&q=hello%20world&source=en&target=de";
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSLog(@"%@",request);

NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                             returningResponse:nil
                                                         error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",response);
NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
NSArray *retrievedJTrans = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
NSLog(@"%@",retrievedJTrans);
NSDictionary *translation;
for(int i=0; i<[retrievedJTrans count];i++)
{
    translation=[retrievedJTrans objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"Statuses: %@", [translation objectForKey:@"translatedText"]);
}
NSLog(@"%@",[translation class]);
```

I am trying to retrieve the translated text from this simple JSON:

```
{
    "data": {
        "translations": [
            {
                "translatedText": "Hallo Welt"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But I am getting the error:

```
-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Any help is appreciated. Using latest Xcode.

Comment: dupe of many others... your json is a dict not an array it seems

Comment: Your dictionary does not have indices. In general ist a good idea to check for the class of the objects, that come out of a json serialisation.

Comment: See json.org and learn the JSON syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *retrievedJTrans = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
```

is a dictionary

what you might want

```
NSDictionary *retrievedJTransD = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
NSArray *retrievedJTrans = retrievedJTransD[@"data"][@"translations"];
```

Answer (score 2):

See this line:

```
NSArray *retrievedJTrans = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
```

You are assuming that the JSON returned to you is an array, but the error message is telling you that it is an NSDictionary. a little test you can use is:

```
id receivedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
if ([receivedObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    // Process the object as a dictionary
} else {
    // Process the object as an array
}
```